# Substituting Visual C++ frontend to one of the previous version

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile [The Point Cloud Library (PCL)](http://pointclouds.org/) from sources in Visual Studio 2013 (with v120 toolset and MSCL18 of course) because I need this library for a VS2013 project. It turned out a tricky task, though.

- On one hand, PCL sources aren't compiled in VS2013 because of breaking
  changes in new C++ standard templates in VS2013
- On the other hand, when compiled in VS2012, PCL DLLs have their own
  CRT and even simplest PCL related code crashes

For example, in VS2013 this code snippet:

```
pcl::console::print_highlight(stdout, "Begin");
```

throws an exception at "EnterCriticalSection(&(((_FILEX *) pf)->lock));", which is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996523/fflushstdout-crashing-issue-with-visual-studio-2012), due to different CRTs in PCL DLLs and my EXE.

As a last resort I'm trying to change C++ frontend from MSCL18 to MSCL17 in order to receive object or assembler files and link them  on the further build step with the CL18 linker. I didn't find a good way to do it yet.

So my question is if anybody may share their experience in such a two-step compilation, how to substitute the previous compiler version frontend or what may be another solution in this problem?

Comment: This won't work because you have to use the Standard Library that matches the toolchain version (so, if you use the Visual C++ 2012 compiler you need to use the Visual C++ 2012 libraries as well, and likewise for Visual C++ 2013).  You cannot link objects that are compiled using different versions of the libraries (doing so would cause ODR violations and worse).  If you need to mix-and-match, you'll need to do so using dynamic libraries with a C (or COM) interface between them.

Comment: Great notice. I reviewed STL difference. It is almost the same for the both compilers, besides some new methods and new C++ standards decorations. So the data should pass okay.

Comment: _Almost the same_ is not _the same._  As one of the people who made changes to the Visual C++ libraries for Visual C++ 2013, I can tell you that trying to mix-and-match is perilous and will almost assuredly end in tears.  99.99% of the issues that you could possibly run into are not diagnosable at compile-time and manifest themselves as obscure, sometimes not-reliably-reproducable runtime crashes.  This is why, by default, we forbid linking mismatched objects.

Comment: I've just made everything compilable and I'm going to try what I get. The changes, which I did are (1) changing "= delete" constructors to private ones,  (2) removing explicit keyword on bool converters, (3) removing initializer_list<> constructors for basic_string<> and (4) changing templates in two other basic_string<> constructors. That's it and it looks quite simple changes, especially as there are no string creations. I'm going to set it on fire and see how it will go.

Comment: James, you sound quite solid. I understand what you're saying. I'm just trying to find ways to get my job done. Besides this idea with substituting C++ frontend and subset of STL, what would you recommend? What did I possibly overlook?

Comment: The correct and supported way to do this is to link the Visual C++ 2012-compiled objects into one module (DLL) and link the Visual C++ 2013-compiled objects into a different module, then use a C (or COM) interface between the DLLs and avoid sharing runtime state across the boundary (e.g., don't malloc through one runtime and free through another; don't use a FILE* from one runtime with the stdio functions of another; etc.).  This can be a pain, yes, especially when encapsulating libraries that make heavy use of "advanced" C++ features on their surface.  But this technique is guaranteed to work

Comment: The best alternative to this would be to fix the PCL sources to build correctly with the Visual C++ 2013 toolchain and libraries.  Whether this is possible for you to do (or how much work it would be), I do not know.  I don't know anything about this PCL library.

Comment: Substituting the front-end worked as a charm. No any problem for long period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few approaches to compile this 3rd party library without changing the library source code. The one, which turned out to work OK, was substituting VS2013 C++ front-end (toolset v120, MSCL18) with the previous one (VS2012, toolset v110, MSCL17) for some files, which don't go through VS2013, and afterwards using resulting OBJ files in further compilation in VS2013.

The James McNellis's remarks did a great job as they helped me better understand and carefully fix compilation errors in VS2013 STL stream and string objects and come out with my subset of VS2013 STL which compiled fine with VS2012 native toolset.

Actually, I created a Custom Build Tool (C++ Project -> Properties) for different configuration and platforms:

```
Debug|Win32
$(ComSpec) /c ""$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" x86   && cl.exe /c %(FullPath) /IC:\Src\PCLCompilation\local_stl /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/boost_1_55_0 /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/eigen/include /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/flann-1.8.4.v120/include" /I"$(SolutionDir)include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/common/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/octree/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/io/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/filters/include" /nologo /W3 /WX- /MP4 /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /Zi /D_MSC_VER=1800 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D _DEBUG /D BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS /D EIGEN_NO_DEBUG /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D NOMINMAX /D BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC /D EIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR /D EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET /D FLANN_STATIC /D CMAKE_INTDIR=$(Configuration) /D PCLAPI_EXPORTS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /arch:SSE2 /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp /Fo"$(IntDir)\" /Fd"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4800 /wd4521 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4305 /wd4355 /wd4800 /wd4521 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4305 /wd4355 /analyze- /errorReport:prompt /bigobj"
Debug|x64
$(ComSpec) /c ""$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64           && cl.exe /c %(FullPath) /IC:\Src\PCLCompilation\local_stl /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/boost_1_55_0 /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/eigen/include /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/flann-1.8.4.v120/include" /I"$(SolutionDir)include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/common/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/octree/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/io/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/filters/include" /nologo /W3 /WX- /MP4 /Od /Ob0      /Zi /D_MSC_VER=1800 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D _DEBUG /D BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS /D EIGEN_NO_DEBUG /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D NOMINMAX /D BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC /D EIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR /D EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET /D FLANN_STATIC /D CMAKE_INTDIR=$(Configuration) /D PCLAPI_EXPORTS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /arch:SSE2 /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp /Fo"$(IntDir)\" /Fd"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4800 /wd4521 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4305 /wd4355                                                           /errorReport:prompt /bigobj"

Release|Win32
$(ComSpec) /c ""$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" x86   && cl.exe /c %(FullPath) /IC:\Src\PCLCompilation\local_stl /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/boost_1_55_0 /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/eigen/include /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/flann-1.8.4.v120/include" /I"$(SolutionDir)include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/common/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/octree/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/io/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/filters/include" /nologo /W3 /WX- /MP4 /O2 /Ob2 /Oy- /GL /D_MSC_VER=1800 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS /D EIGEN_NO_DEBUG /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D NOMINMAX /D BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC /D EIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR /D EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET /D FLANN_STATIC /D CMAKE_INTDIR=$(Configuration) /D PCLAPI_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /arch:AVX /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp /Fo"$(IntDir)\" /Fd"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4800 /wd4521 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4305 /wd4355 /analyze- /errorReport:prompt  /bigobj"
Release|x64
$(ComSpec) /c ""$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64           && cl.exe /c %(FullPath) /IC:\Src\PCLCompilation\local_stl /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/boost_1_55_0 /IC:/Src/PCLCompilation/eigen/include /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/flann-1.8.4.v120/include" /I"$(SolutionDir)include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/common/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/octree/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/io/include" /I"C:/Src/PCLCompilation/pcl-master/filters/include" /nologo /W3 /WX- /MP4 /O2 /Ob2      /GL /D_MSC_VER=1800 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS /D EIGEN_NO_DEBUG /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D NOMINMAX /D BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC /D EIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR /D EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET /D FLANN_STATIC /D CMAKE_INTDIR=$(Configuration) /D PCLAPI_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /arch:AVX /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp /Fo"$(IntDir)\" /Fd"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4800 /wd4521 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4305 /wd4355 /errorReport:prompt /bigobj"
```

With the following Outputs:

```
$(IntDir)%(Filename).obj
```

I changed the tool for uncompilable files to this Custom Build Tool (C++ file -> Properties -> General -> Item Type -> Custom Build Tool) and it nicely went along with the whole compilation process. The string object binary representation looked identical, the resulting binary DLLs worked no problem and all the system passed all our QA tests. 
This small hack helped us to move all our system to VS2013, which was delayed because of a few files in a library, we were dependent of.

**March 30 UPDATE:** We didn't find any error with this approach for a few month on several dev and test boxes.

Comment: You are going to regret this some day.  Pretty stunning that nobody has yet added this issue to the project's bug tracker.  Highly recommended to avoid hackorama like this.

Comment: I understand that this is a hack and so I have a plan B to roll back to VS2012 whenever I meet the real problem. The reality is that we use this library under quite a heavy load in multiple runs and no any problem happened for last two weeks. So I'm hoping it's going to be OK